# why does this angular directive not update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this angular directive:

```
app.directive("apiError", function() {
    return {
        require: "apiUrls",
        template: '{{errors.length}}',
        controller: ["$scope", "$attrs", "ApiError", function($scope, $attrs, ApiError) {
            $scope.errors = ApiError.errors;
        }]
    }
});
```

Which is used in code like this:

```
<div api-error api-urls="['api/login']"></div>
```

ApiError is a service that houses all of the errors coming from the server side. It is definitely being populated.

If I change $scope.errors = ApiError.errors; to $scope.errors = ["blah"]; then the page displays 1, so (I think) it isn't a problem of naming.

Edit: Request to post the source of ApiError:

```
app.service("ApiError", [function () {
    this.errors = [];

    this.setError = function(apiUrl, apiMethod, apiResponseData) {
        this.errors[apiUrl] = this.errors[apiUrl] || [];
        this.errors[apiUrl][apiMethod] = apiResponseData;
    };

    this.removeError = function(apiUrl, apiMethod) {
        if(this.errors[apiUrl] && this.errors[apiUrl][apiMethod]) {
            delete this.errors[apiUrl][apiMethod];
        }

        if(this.errors[apiUrl] && this.errors[apiUrl].length === 0) {
            delete this.errors[apiUrl];
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the source for ApiError? Or at least the relevant sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not listening (or watching) for changes in the errors array of the service. So when the code runs, the errors array is empty, and if it becomes populated later, it won't be reflected inside of your directive.

```
controller: ["$scope", "$attrs", "ApiError", function($scope, $attrs, ApiError) {
        $scope.$watch(function(){return ApiError.errors;}, function(errors){
          $scope.errors = errors;
      });
 }]
```

Comment: unfortunately this watch function does not fire when ApiError.errors is updated. It does however fire when I reload the page, interestingly.

Comment: In that case, you need something like an emit/broadcast mechanism, where the service emits an update and the controller of the directive listens to it and updates the scope variable.

You can read about it here [http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html)

Comment: so it turns out I didnt actually need a service at all, just subscribe to the error events in the controller for the directive. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're `ApiError.errors` is actually an Object that is keyed with the url for the error, and not an Array. It therefore doesn't have a `.length` method. You could, however, get the number of keys for that object: `Object.keys(ApiError.errors).length`

Comment: I changed it to this.errors = []; and now I get a 0, but it still doesnt update.

Comment: How does the `setErrors` function get called? In Angular, you have to make sure that a digest cycle is invoked after you update some data. This is what will sync the data with the UI. Many angular services (such as `$http`) will fire a digest cycle when they've completed. Depending on how you're invoking the `setError` function, you might not be setting off a digest.